# My Parents have been fighting heavily and today they said they are seriously considering divorce how can I prevent

Tags: divorce, father, mother

I am a teenager with a younger sister today my parents said they are considering divorce. I haven’t been able to relax since. If this were to happen my world would come crashing down they said they still love each other but my dads family is to much for my mom and she is making my dad chose between them or us. What can I do to prevent

Comment: This is a very difficult situation and I'm sorry yuou're going through this. There's nothing you can do to control the actions of others. It's their decision, and though it definitely involved you and your sister, they're the ones who decide. If you have not been to a Family Counselor, that's something that you're certtainly within your rights to ask for. Good luck.

Comment: i had to make this choice as a parent. I chose my partner and children (biological children or not). Your dad should make a choice also; it depdnds upon how reasonable your mother's issues with his family are.